# find indexes of minimum points in moving time window in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

### The Problem

I have a dataframe which looks like this (the indexes are actually dates):

```
    col1  col2 
0   40.0  0 
1   22.0  0 
2   30.0  0 
3   29.1  0
4   20.0  0
5   17.2  0
6   44.5  0
7   30.0  0 
8   19.3  0
9   30.2  0
10  11.7  0 
11  29.1  0
...
```

What I'd like is to find in each moving time window (each time the window shifts by 1) of size `N`, for example 5, to get the indexes of the `K` smallest values in `col1`, for example 2, and set `col2` to `1` in such rows.

So in this example we would look at this window and set the 3 minimal indexes: `1,3,4`, to be `1` in `col2`

```
   col1  col2 
0   40.0  0 
1   22.0  0 
2   30.0  0 
3   29.1  0
4   20.0  0
```

and then at the window here below and set `1,4,5` to be `1` in `col2` (It doesn't matter that we already chose index `1` in the previous window)

```
    col1  col2 
1   22.0  0 
2   30.0  0 
3   29.1  0
4   20.0  0
5   17.2  0
```

and so on...

### What have I tried?

I tried using a for loop but it's **extremely slow**

```
shift_df = df.copy(deep=True)  # create a copy of the df to shift by one each time
for frame in range(len(df.index) - N):
    frame_df = shift_df.head(N)
    df.loc[frame_df.nsmallest(K, 'col1').index.tolist(), 'col2'] = 1
    shift_df = shift_df[1:]
```

I also thought of using `rolling` but couldn't find a way to implement it here.

Comment: With your code I get a `0` in the last row but I guess it should be `1`, shouldn't it?

Answer (score 0):

You can abuse rolling with apply like the following (although I think this is rather ugly):

```
def fun(x):
    df.loc[x.nsmallest(K).index, 'col2'] = 1
    return 0

df.col1.rolling(N).apply(fun)
```

With the 12 rows sample data I get 8.2 ms for rolling and 12.2 ms for the loop.
For 10K rows rolling needs 9.8 s and looping needs 17 s; so rolling is not so much faster, because apply is just a disguised loop.